# Do I understand "As computers became smaller and more powerful so their uses developed within science..." correctly?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the book *"How It works... The Computer":*

> As computers became smaller and more powerful **so their uses** developed within science, technology and business.

How I understand this sentence:

> As computers became smaller and more powerful so **did** their uses **that were** developed within science, technology and business.

Does my paraphrasing sound like I'm on the right track with this sentence?

Comment: This sentence doesn't scan well for me.  _Computers became smaller and more powerful so their uses developed within science, technology and business_ if the author means to imply cause and effect.  _As computers became smaller and more powerful so developed their uses within science, technology and business_ if the author means to imply that the two developments occurred hand in hand.  (As in _As goes Maine, so goes the nation_ meaning that politics in the state of Maine are a good indicator of national trends.

Comment: Well, one sentence is really not enough to make the best judgment about it. The paragraph or at least some surrounding sentences would help. Also, the reading level of the book.

Comment: I think you’ve understood it correctly. That is a strange use of that construction, and normally I’d expect “as. . .so _did.”_

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I don't think you necessarily would in this particular case. It kinda depends on the verb in each clause being the same. If the verbs in the clauses are different, you can't use that construction quite so effectively - although it would still be grammatical: *As computers became smaller and more powerful so did their uses develop within science, technology and business*. (a bit clunky, imo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted sentence is not a good one.

I take it to mean:  as computers became smaller and more powerful, they were put to new uses in science, technology, and business.